# SQL query to change custom field in Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm newbie in SQL questions, and today i have a big problem.

I need change many fields in my SQL, about 4,5k. But have some rules to the query change, to don't change wrong fields where don't need changed.

In table **wp_postmeta** i have four columns:
`meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value`

I need change the value of `meta_value`, *BUT ONLY* if the current value is **'Y'** or **'Empty'** and *REPLACE* to value **'X'**, AND ONLY in lines where `meta_key` value is **old_price**

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend a database backup before you do this.

** updated the statement to specify "Y", empty string, or null **

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "update {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = 'X' WHERE meta_key = 'old_price' AND ( meta_value = 'Y' OR meta_value = '' OR meta_value IS NULL ) );" );
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I use your code like base, and after one "google" i make my code and works great. Thank you for the hep.

Comment: The final code is it: UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'X' WHERE meta_key = 'old_price' AND meta_value LIKE 'Y' OR ''

Comment: Oh I see, empty like "", not "Empty". Should work fine. You probably could have also done, meta_value = "Y" OR meta_value = "" or meta_value IS NULL